# 'For' Loop Within a 'For' Loop and Then Another?

Tags: java

This has confused me quite a bit, but it's also really interesting!

I want to loop through a grid of 9 elements in an array, multiply them all by 1/9. Then, I want to find the sum of those 9 elements and replace each individual element's with the value calculated as the sum. After I've done this, I want to move on to the next nine elements. **To clarify, I want all 9 elements to be changed to myVal, in the code below.**

So far I've got the loop within a loop bit, but I don't know how to then go back and replace each of the values with the sum of all of them combined. Here's my code:-

```
 previousx = 0; 
 previousy= 0;
for (int x = previousx; x < previousx+4; x++) {
    for(int y = previousy; y < previousy+4; y++) {
        y = y*(1/9);
        yVal += y;
      }
 }
```

Any advice would, of course, be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First thing, be sure that y*(1/9) is going to be done using integer arithmetic, so I would suggest converting to double.

Comment: Ah, good point! Thank you

Comment: Could you post the code of your "grid"?

Comment: Your inner loops condition results in a infinite loop...

Comment: @KubaSpatny I'm using a built in java function, getRGB() to get a 2d map of an image's pixels

Answer (score 2):

Note that `y` is an `int`, you probably want to have a variable of type `double` and perform the `double` calculation on it:

```
double myDouble;
for(int y = previousy; x < previousy+4; y++) {
   myDouble = y*((double)1/9);
   yVal += myDouble;
}
```

As @ZouZou mentioned, since the default of numbers in Java is `int`, `1/9` will be 0. You need to cast one side to `double`:

```
((double)1/9)
```

And the other side will be implicitly cast.

Also note that your inner loop doesn't end:

```
for(int y = previousy; x < previousy+4; y++) {
                       ↑
                 Should be y
```

Comment: +1. and cast one of the number to double in (1/9) =)

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't answer my question of how I can change all the 9 values to yVal

Comment: @BenjaminFranklin You can use another loop to replace all the values in the array by yVal.

Comment: @BenjaminFranklin Assign the result to the array.

Comment: thank you Maroun - could you show what you mean by assigning the result to the array? I'm still unsure of how to change the values of the 9 elements to yVal and then move on to the next group of 9

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
int setNum = 1;
for (< exit condition >) {

    // Insert code here to find myVal
    // for current set of 9 elements

    for (; i < 9 * setNum; i++) {
        arr[i] = myVal;
    }
    setNum++;
}
```

EDIT: If `arr` is a 2D array

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    // Insert code here to find myVal
    // for current set of 9 elements

    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = myVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thing is, this works for a 1d array, not a 2d array

Comment: I thought about that too, but then I can't move onto the next 9 elements, because I've exited the loop

Comment: @BenjaminFranklin The outer loop won't exit unless it has finished looping all the rows in the grid.